# Geiser / Emacs hangs when I start Guile web server

Tags: emacs, scheme, guile, geiser

I'm experimenting with Guile and simple web development. I have some experience with Common Lisp and Slime. And I'm a huge fan of interactive development. Geiser is great IDE, however I loose interactivity when I run even simple web server from REPL:

```
(use-modules (web server))

(define (hello-world-handler request request-body)
  (values '((content-type . (text/plain)))
          "hello"))

(run-server hello-world-handler)
```

After that, if I try to ie evaluate definition, nothing happens and Emacs hangs. When I hit C-g Emacs works again, but it's getting worse after that - in REPL every Geiser function hangs - for example if I hit TAB or C-M-i to complete symbol. I can only type text and hit ENTER. The only solution is to kill Scheme interpreter with C-c C-q and start it again. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Tested on Guile v2.2 + latest Geiser and Guile v2.0 + Geiser v0.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to run a separate Guile process from command line using `--listen` parameter, ie:

```
guile --listen=1661 web-test.scm
```

and connect with it from Emacs using **`M-x geiser-connect`** or **`M-x connect-to-guile`**, as explained in the *"connecting to an external scheme"* here: http://geiser.nongnu.org/geiser_3.html#Starting-the-REPL.

Solved with the help of Geiser maintainer.